# I updated my Laravel 6 application key and login now returns 419 error despite valid csrf

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I recently used `php artisan key:generate` to update my Laravel 6 application key in what I've since learned was a misguided attempt to fix a 419 error returned by an AJAX call. Since then I cannot even log in, as I get a 419 error.

All my searches tell me that the issue is that a CSRF token has not been set, has not been included in the form, or is invalid; but I've verified that it is OK, and being sent with the form.

I'm not even sure what code I should post because I have no idea what the problem is... but here's the .env file contents.

```
APP_NAME="Venues"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY='base64:AZ7uqZVGit5vYuV2TLToM/6SAK+/wfi+BWnNICcXPxo='
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=************
APP_DIR=************
LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=************
DB_USERNAME=************
DB_PASSWORD=************

BARS_FAVICON="${APP_URL}ec-favicon-loc.ico"
BARS_APP="${APP_DIR}app/"
BARS_RESOURCES="${APP_DIR}resources/"
BARS_JS="${APP_URL}js/"
BARS_CSS_URL="${APP_URL}css/"
BARS_CSS_DIR="${APP_DIR}public/css/"
BARS_IMGS_DIR="${APP_DIR}public/images/"
BARS_IMGS_URL="${APP_URL}images/"

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=${APP_URL}

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

`login.blade.php` is the default login form as it is out of the box, haven't changed anything. In fact I have made no changes to any default authentication-related files.

Please let me know if there's any info I should add.

**Update**
Don't know why I didn't mention this in the first place, but I have cleared all site cookies, cache, and browser history. I have also tried the artisan commands `config:cache`, `config:clear`. I also ran `rm -f storage/framework/sessions/*`.

Comment: clear your cookies related to your site

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that... should have mentioned in my question. Will update.